# ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter method is really slow

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a performance issue using ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter method.

I have to print a (small) report from a WebService running under IIS 6.0 on Win Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64. The print report method hangs for about 20 seconds and i can't figure out why.

```
rpDoc.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

-I don't have problems on my pc, the application works fine.
-There are no problems on loading the report.
-Printer access is ok (it's installed on the server).
-Verify On Every Print / DB ecc ecc is all unchecked.
-I use Vs2008, Crystal Reports V. 10.5.37 and 3.5 Framework

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

At the end the problem was a setting of the Application Pool in IIS Configuration.
The Virtual Memory Limit was to low, when reached widows force a recycle, discarding all the CR assemblies.
The 20 seconds hang was caused by reloading all resources needed.

Comment: thanks for coming back and answering this question, I regret I have but one upvote to give...